# I need you to resize the image and save it in a specific path, is it possible? (Sharp)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need sharp to resize an image and save it in a specific directory ... Is it possible?

The code below resizes as needed, but saved in the local folder where I am running the program. I need that as a way of output, sharp save the file in a specific directory such as: C: \ Users \ mathe \ Desktop is it possible?

```
var cria = (imagem, largura, altura, arquivo)=>{
    sharp(imagem)
    .resize(largura, altura).toFile(arquivo, (err)=>{
        if(!err){
            console.log('Sucess') //Creates the file with the correct parameters but saved in the local folder
        }else{
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the library (sharp)

Comment: Not knowing any Spanish(?) nor Sharp, but passing in `arquivo` as a full path would seem to be the obvious solution.